# Stuffing bread for the next day

Tags: bread, dough, storage

Can you make your dough and stuff it/roll it with meat or whatever you choose, then place it in fridge overnight to be cooked the next day?

What I mean is, do everything like you are about to bake but instead of putting it in the oven, you put it in fridge. Will it keep and bake right the next day?

Comment: If you are thinking of a particular recipe, please post it.

Comment: Which meat are you going to bake?

Answer (score 3):

The dough should be fine retarded overnight on it's own. What you are asking really depends on the filling. If you are filling the dough with something that has a tendency to "weep" or lose water, it can negatively effect your finished product. The water will be stuck in the cavity and can make your bread soggy and hard to bake completely.

If your filing contains sugar, it can draw moisture out of your dough. This will create a syrup and can also lead to sogginess, though it's more likely to lead to a thick caramel shell wherever the liquid leaks out. Salty fillings can also cause unpredictable results.

I think your best bet would be to make the dough, portion it, then retard the dough by itself. Let your dough portions warm up again before you're ready to bake and then fill them as close to the baking time as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming this is a yeast-based dough, this is called retarding the dough, and if your dough is well-wrapped it should work out just fine. Beyond the convenience, there is actually one advantage to this method: the flavor of the dough tends to become more complex with the slow fermentation that the refrigerator will effect. Generally, it's best to refrigerate after you're confident the dough has a good active yeast culture, so I would recommend letting it rise a bit before stuffing.

The main caveat is that, for best results, you'll want the yeast to become active again before baking, which you'll need to balance with the total time that the meat might be in the danger zone for bacterial growth.

I usually find an hour in a warm room to be sufficient, but if it's cold weather or you keep your room cooler than 70F, you might be flirting with too much time in the danger zone. My oven happens to have a rapid-proofing feature and I find I can get the same effect by proofing for 25-30 minutes, then a more gentle rise while the oven preheats.

If you're using something other than a yeast dough, such as a pie dough, puff pastry or empanada style dough, then overnight refrigeration has no such complications.

Do keep in mind that regardless of what kind of pastry you're making, you don't want the raw pastries to touch each other, as they'll tend to stick together.

Comment: Thank you both. I would only be using cooked meats and cheeses as the stuffing and it is yeast dough. I think I may try it once just to see how it plays out. I am contemplating this as a business when I retire. I am kinda tweaking my wife's recipes to make different things. I am trying to save time by prepping the evening before so there is less work in the morning. I really want it fresh every day as opposed to cooked the day before like I think some people do. Thanks again. Robert